# SVGKit how to enumerateChildLayersUsingBlock?

Tags: ios, svg

Using SVGKit, I am now looking for some sample code on how to use the enumerateChildLayersUsingBlock method.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found some code like this:

```
    CALayer *f = [document layerTree],*x;

    for(int i = 0; i < [f.sublayers count]; i++) {
        x=(CALayer*)[f.sublayers objectAtIndex:i];
        if([x isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]]) {
            // DO SOME WORK.
        }
    }
```

It is not actually an example of enumerateChildLayersUsingBlock usage,but it does basically what I need. So that'll do at least for a while. I will dig more into the subject when I really need something recursive.